# How to access temptable after creating it dynamically

Tags: sql-server

I am using the statement

```
SELECT    * 
INTO      #gsig_ref  
FROM      gsign 
WHERE     [name] NOT LIKE 'RESERVE%' OR [name] NOT LIKE 'Spare%'



EXECUTE('SELECT * INTO #db1 FROM ' + @db1)
EXECUTE('SELECT * INTO #db2 FROM ' + @db2)
```

where `@db1` will be supplied at runtime (for eg `@db1 = '#gsig_ref'`)

If I say `select * from #db1`... it says invalid object.
Please help me how to access data from `#db1`.. since i have use this in another query like

```
SELECT        DISTINCT @p1 INTO #curs_name
FROM          #db1 
WHERE         @p1 NOT IN (SELECT @p2 FROM #db2)
ORDER BY      @p1
```

How can `#db1` be acccessed in the above query and also `@p1` is the input variable to this procedure and I should use it for the `distinct @p1`..

Comment: :( :(... should be still higher ?? :( :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local temporary table that is created in a stored procedure is dropped when the procedure ends; other stored procedures, or the calling process, can't see them.

You could generate the entire SQL, effectively moving the temporary table to the dynamic SQL, like:

```
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = 'select into #t1 ....; select * from #t1';
exec (@sql);
```

If I read that, I wonder why your outer procedure even needs the temporary table, but there may be good reasons for that.

Another option, if you're sure only one call is executed at the same time, is to use a global temp table.  They're declared with a double hash, like `##TempTable`.  Global temp tables survive the end of their procedure, but can be referenced from multiple sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access temp tables declared in dynamic SQL.

However, if you create a temp table before running a dynamic query, you can reference it in that dynamic query.

In your example, this would become

```
CREATE TABLE #db1
(...table definition...)

CREATE TABLE #db2
(...table definition...)

EXECUTE('INSERT #db1 SELECT * FROM ' + @db1)
EXECUTE('INSERT #db2 SELECT * FROM ' + @db2)
```

You will also need to construct and execute your second query (using `@p1`) as dynamic SQL, since you want to use variables as placeholders for column names.

**EDIT**

There is no simple way to modify this solution if the structure of your source tables varies.

You could write some code to query the information schema to generate and apply dynamic `ALTER TABLE` scripts to the temp table to make its structure match the source table, but this may be more complexity than you're willing to take on.

Andomar's suggestion of carrying out the whole operation in dynamic SQL may be a better fit.

It might be a good idea to take a step back and re-evaluate whether what you're trying to do is the best solution to whatever problem it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Harper, thanks for the suggestion.
But, @db1 is not a single table..it keeps changing and I cant have the CREATE TABLE #db1 for one table, as the structure changes for every value of @db1. 
So, I had this option earlier and i quitted it as it will not work out for me.
Any other suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference variables declared in the EXEC(like your temp tables) statement outside that statement.

Comment: HI.. I am able to solve the temp tables by creating them as regular tables and dropping them at the end. but I have a select statemetn which is
SELECT DISTINCT @p1 as col1 INTO #curs_name
FROM db1
WHERE @p1 NOT IN (SELECT @p2 FROM db2)
ORDER BY case when @p1 = 'name' then @p1
when @p1 = 'param' then @p1
else @p1
end
The error displayed is "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." Actually @p1 is sent as param to this proc it may be changing at runtime. How to handle this in this situatoin ?Is this same case for @p2??
Please help .
Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 0):

Create temp tables in advance before the dynamic sql and then populate then using dynamic sql.

Refer 4th method in http://www.nigelrivett.net/SQLTsql/AccessTempTablesAcrossSPs.html

Hope this helps!